# Blocked a frame with origin "https://tpc.googlesyndication.com" from accessing a frame with origin "". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: safari, cross-domain, double-click

I have doubleclick ads in my website.
When I open the website with my iPad (iOS version 9.3.5 Safari), I see the following [error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIOfT.png):

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://tpc.googlesyndication.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://mywebsite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

** Replaced my website's url with "https://mywebsite.com"

Seems like this error is written to the log in an infinity loop. As you can see in the screenshot, the error was printed to the console 122.6K times.

In Chrome I didn't see these errors.

Why is it happening? Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks alot!

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Any update?????

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a cross origin policy setup by Safari. You can simulate what it would be like to fix this by going to the Developer menu and selecting "Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions."

That will not solve it for your users though, and you have to include an exception for the domain when trusted by modifying the headers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin